# Shortcode Custom Content display condition from advance custom, choices, in feild type - select

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to write WordPress shortcodes using Custom Content and Advanced Custom Fields so that if choice (select field type) in "field_status" is equal to Not Playable, it displays Not Playable in red. If choice is equal to Playble it displays Playable as normal.

```
\[repeater fieldslist\]

\[if field=field_status contains=not-playble\]

- **\[field name_of_the_field\] -**\[field field_status\] (field status is in red text)

\[/if\]

\[if field=field_status value=please-select\]

- **\[field name_of_the_field\] -**\[field field_status\]

\[/if\]

\[/repeater\]

\[/loop\]
```

I need something that displays the field in a given color, given specified condition is met

I'm not sure if this is even possible without using PHP or CSS, but I would appreciate the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want create like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode ', 'shortcode_by_options' );
function shortcode_by_options( $atts, $content = null ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'attr_1' => 'attribute 1 default',
    'attr_2' => 'attribute 2 default',
    // ...etc
), $atts );

return '<span class="' . esc_attr($a['attr_1']) . '">' . $content . '</span>';
}
```

and use this shortcode like this :

```
[myshortcode attr_1="bar" attr_2="bing"]
```